# React Native Animated don't fire onScroll event in FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist, react-animated

i'm broking my head trying solving this problem.

In an Expo project i have a FlatList and onScroll event i'd like to change the Animated value, but nothing happen.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, Animated } from 'react-native';

import ProductItem from './ProductItem';

const HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT = 250;
const HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT = 88;
const CARD_MAX_SCALE = 1;
const CARD_MIN_SCALE = 0.5;

const ProductsList = (props) => {
    const { products, onSelect, onDelete } = props;

    const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const onScrollHandler = Animated.event([{
        nativeEvent: {
            contentOffset: { y: scrollY }
        }
    }],
        { useNativeDriver: true }
    );

    const height = scrollY.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT - HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT],
        outputRange: [HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT, HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT],
        extrapolateRight: 'clamp'
    });


    console.log(scrollY); // Never log a new value, never rerender component

    return (
        <View style={styles.listContainer}>
            <Animated.FlatList
                {...props}
                scrollEventThrottle={16}
                data={products}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => <ProductItem product={item} onPress={() => { onSelect(item) }} onDelete={onDelete} />}
                onScroll={onScrollHandler}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    listContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: '20%',
        paddingBottom: 10,
    }
});

export default ProductsList;
```

Where i'm wrong?

I have also installed react-native-reanimated V2, may it cause the issue?

I don't know what to think anymore

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example How to use Animated FlatList Click [here](https://snack.expo.io/@j-rayhan/animated-flatlist-and-header)

Comment: Yeah! Is the same like mine it seems, but doesn't work

Comment: @Rayhan did you check that code? It doesn't work.